# Fltk channel receiver misses some messages

Tags: rust, channel

I create an fltk window with a button. When clicked, the button spawns a thread with 10 iterations inside. Each iteration sends a message to the channel. With println!() everything works fine, but if I delete it - the channel starts skipping some messages.

```
[dependencies]
fltk = { version="1.2.23", features=["fltk-bundled"] }
fltk-evented = "0.1"
```

```rust
use fltk::{prelude::*, *};
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc, thread};

fn main() {
    //create channel
    let (mainSender, mainReceiver) = app::channel::<i32>();

    //create application, window, button
    let mainApp = app::App::default();
    let mut win = window::Window::default().with_size(500, 500);
    let mut btn = button::Button::new(20, 20, 100, 40, "START");

    win.end();
    win.show();

    let mainSenderClone = mainSender.clone();

    btn.handle(move |thisBtn, evt| match evt {
        //btn event handler
        enums::Event::Push => {
            //click event

            thread::spawn(move || {
                //create thread

                let mut cnt = 0; //10 iterations
                while (cnt < 10) {
                    mainSenderClone.send(cnt);
                    //println!("sent_from_thread: {}",cnt); - uncommenting this fixes the situation
                    cnt += 1;
                }
            });

            true //event handled
        }

        _ => false, //ignore other events
    });

    //start listening
    while mainApp.wait() {
        if let Some(msg) = mainReceiver.recv() {
            println!("RECEIVED: {}", msg);
        }
    }
}
```

The output (without println!() in the thread):

```
RECEIVED: 1
RECEIVED: 3
RECEIVED: 5
RECEIVED: 7
RECEIVED: 9
```

With println!():

```
sent_from_thread: 0
RECEIVED: 0
sent_from_thread: 1
RECEIVED: 1
sent_from_thread: 2
RECEIVED: 2
sent_from_thread: 3
RECEIVED: 3
sent_from_thread: 4
RECEIVED: 4
sent_from_thread: 5
RECEIVED: 5
sent_from_thread: 6
RECEIVED: 6
sent_from_thread: 7
RECEIVED: 7
sent_from_thread: 8
RECEIVED: 8
sent_from_thread: 9
RECEIVED: 9
```

Comment: Can you please format your code when posting questions? It's only one command, `cargo fmt`, and it helps people help you.

Comment: This isn't a problem you'd observe with just the std or crossbeam channels. So you should probably ask the authors of this fltk crate, maybe create an issue.

Comment: @denys-séguret tried creating a question with "ftlk" tag, but one of the FLTK developers told me I should remove the tag because the problem has nothing to do with FLTK (his name was albrecht-schlosser) https://prnt.sc/24rm0os

Comment: @fewrandom I can't reproduce the problem you have with just std (mspc) channels & threads part (I don't want to try compile fltk). See: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a7eea8d1ced4921287f864a8d542d3db

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue on my macbook with app::channel. I got all the numbers received and printed out with the `println!` line commented out.

Comment: @joe-jingyu wow, thats really weird. Could you please share the project you created, maybe I'm missing some silly mistake. I would really appreciate. Because at this point I have no idea what can be wrong. My email (if needed) fewrandom@gmail.com

Comment: I double checked my Cargo.toml and main.rs are exactly same as what you posted. Maybe there is something else different between our environments. If you have another machine, maybe you can try to replicate on it and see if the issue is machine related.

Answer (score 0):

So, after few days of learning magic, I decided to do "**cargo update + build**" and then everything started working properly.

I still don't quite understand what was that and how did the previous downloaded dependencies get corrupted, but.. yeah, updating fixed it

Another question, I still dont get why sometimes the channel receives all the 10 messages immediately, and sometimes 0123 [1-2 seconds pause] 456789. But I think I will eventually find it out

Thanks to everyone who took my code and tested it, especially @denys-séguret, @joe-jingyu

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, receiver missing almost half events.

Mine was caused by having two **app:channels** and two **app::add_idle3**.

When I deleted one of the app::add_idle3, the other started receiving all events.

```
let (sender_window, receiver_area): (Sender<[usize; 2]>, Receiver<[usize; 2]>) = app::channel();
let (sender_machine, receiver_frame): (Sender<Vec<u8>>, Receiver<Vec<u8>>) = app::channel();

app::add_idle3(move |_| {
    if let Some(msg) = receiver_frame.recv() {
    ...    
}
});
app::add_idle3(move |_| {
    if let Some(msg) = receiver_area.recv() {
    ...    
    }
});
```

It looks to me like fltk-rs bug.